# After host website when click submit button for enter data, logout from account. but not in local server.

Tags: php, forms

I created a website. it allow to admin to enter some data to the database. admin has data enter panel and others cannot access it. this page protected with user name and password.
If admin wants to add data should log to the page. logging form created with PHP.
this screen shot shows the admin panel.[this form allows to enter result to the database by clicking submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdSSF.png)

but the thing is when click submit button for submit result logout from admin page in each time. i have to login again for enter new result. but it only happen after host the site.

when i create website i used xampp server. when i test it locally it was not happened. what is happening here and i want to fix it immediately.
this is some code parts related to that.

Logging part and start session.

```
if ($root=='root') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM subadmin WHERE uname = '$uname' AND 
password='$password'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (!$row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
header("Location: ../formPage/login.php?error=notmatch");
exit();

}
else{
$_SESSION['uname']= $row['uname'];
header("Location: ../subadmin/table1.php");
}

}
```

Logout button part

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["uname"]=NULL;
header('Location:  ../formpage/login.php');
die;
?>
```

top of admin page

```
<?php 
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['uname']==NULL) {
    header('Location:  ../formpage/login.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: What are you storing in your `$root`?

Comment: $root is just a variable. when fill logging form get one of text box value to $root variable and it should equal to "root". it is only for security purposes.

Comment: Will you provide your raw code in pastebin?